# Why when I run tf.exe unshelve /migrate between branches, it changes my file move operations into file add?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, devops

Why when I run `tf.exe unshelve /migrate` between branches, it changes my **file move** operations into **file add**?

Is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is expected behavior. In TFVC, branches are treated as separate entities to isolate risk. So, when using `tf.exe unshelve /migrate` command between branches, it converts a file move operation into a file addition operation in the target branch.